# Java Vector3D method priorities

Tags: java

Which methods would be prioritized from math.geom3d.Vector3D class? Would .times be performed before .minus, just like regularly with scalars?

I found [this guide for order of operators](http://web.deu.edu.tr/doc/oreily/java/langref/ch04_14.htm), but it didn't answer my question.

Unfortunately I don't have how to compile Java code and "experiment" to see the results.

```
Vector3D ey = new Vector3D(aPosition,cPosition).minus(ex.times(i)).times(1/(new Vector3D(aPosition,cPosition).minus(ex.times(i)).norm()));
```

I imagine it would begin as the following, from the end of the line:

1. (new Vector3D(aPosition,cPosition).minus(ex.times(i)), where .times is executed first and .minus next
2. .norm of the resulting vector
3. 1 divided by the norm
4. ??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Order of operation only applies to infix operators. This would be executed in the same order as any other method calls: inner first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no special rules for any class in Java when calling methods on objects. It is just like any other object.

When you do

```
obj.method1(...).method2(...).method3(...);
```

This will execute method1 and then method2 and then method3.

Every method will be executed only after all of its parameters have been evaluated.